# how Call a signalR function just for web API Caller by c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr-hub

I need to callback a function on the client who has just called the Web API method. I can send back to all users but I just need to call for JUST the caller.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public WebResult Logout()
        {
     var cc =Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventsHub>();
         cc.Clients.All.TestLogOut();
        }
```

I know it might be possible if I have the connectionId for the caller, but I do not know how it can be?

Plus, it seems there is something IHbubCallerContext... what is it and can it be helpful. if can get the caller and the connectioId!

```
cc.Clients.Client("ConnectionId").TestLogoutCurrent();
```

***HOW TO CallBack a Caller function OR how  to get the caller connectionId ?***

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution , it seems we cannot get connection Id in web API,
so we need to create a HUB class and call a method from client. in that method we have caller and connection ID, so we are able to callback on this method.

```
public class EventHub : Hub

    {
        public void LogOutSignalRTest()
        {

            var cc = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventsHub>();
                cc.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).clientlogout();

        }

    }
```

the context here is type of HubCallerContext, so we have the connection ID , 
clientlogout is a function on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function on the Caller client from within your SignalR Hub implementation:

```
[HubName("MyHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void logout()
    {
        Clients.Caller.clientLogout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems I have to call  TWO logout functions from client. one is web API , and the other is signalR which called from client, and in the signalR call back to client (which your code is second ) because we have the connection Id just in signalR hub classes. but if there is a more structured way , not so complicated like our scenario, is so much better. Thanks for your response

Comment: You can have a single logout function if you pass the client's SignalR connection id via the Web API call, then you can use cc.Clients.Client("ConnectionId").TestLogoutCurrent()

Comment: would you put this lines of codes for me? an example

Comment: as I know the connectionId JUST comes with SignalR connection not webAPI request!! The client cannot put the connection ID in web API request.

Comment: you can pass it as part of the body of the request!